# role of discrete wpf Dependency Property get and set extentions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Given this source: [external code base](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF)

and this static class specifically:

```
public static class TreeViewItemBehavior
{

public static bool GetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
{
    return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);
}

public static void SetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(
  TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
{
    treeViewItem.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(TreeViewItemBehavior),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));

static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(
  DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem item = depObj as TreeViewItem;
    if (item == null)
        return;

    if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
        return;

    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        item.Selected += OnTreeViewItemSelected;
    else
        item.Selected -= OnTreeViewItemSelected;
}

static void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Only react to the Selected event raised by the TreeViewItem
    // whose IsSelected property was modified. Ignore all ancestors
    // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired.
    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
        return;

    TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    if (item != null)
        item.BringIntoView();
}

#endregion // IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected
```

}

What is the role of the "Get" and "Set" prefixed methods? Adding this Class, and in XAML setting a TreeView.ItemControlsStyle Setter Property to the static Dependency Property, and its Value to "True"works as expected. If I comment out BOTH the get and set prefixed methods and recompile, Intellisense complains that the Property of the style cannot be null, yet compilation is still successful, AND the functionality of

```
static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(
DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
```

**is maintained**.

The complaint remains if both method names are changed in any way, the complaint is absent if only one method is commented-out/modified.

Is this an alternate means of implementing property get and set? Does the control automatically seek a  'Get/Set + PropertyName' extention method in XAML?
How/Why is this able to work when the get and set extentions are disabled/commented out? The class and the xaml ref can be found at the specified link. I modified the specified XAML property ref by declaring it as x:Static, and that is the only modification. Thanks for any insight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the documentation:

[DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached Method (String, Type, Type, PropertyMetadata, ValidateValueCallback)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597496(v=vs.110).aspx)

leads you to [attached-properties-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview#custom-attached-properties) where creation of them is described in detail:

Excerpt:

> **How to Create an Attached Property**
>
> If your class is defining the attached property strictly for use on other types, then the class does not have to derive from DependencyObject. But you do need to derive from DependencyObject if you follow the overall WPF model of having your attached property also be a dependency property.
>
> Define your attached property as a dependency property by declaring a `public` `static` `readonly` field of type `DependencyProperty`. You define this field by using the return value of the RegisterAttached method. The field name must match the attached property name, appended with the string Property, to follow the established WPF pattern of naming the identifying fields versus the properties that they represent. *The attached property provider must also provide `static` **`Get`PropertyName** and **`Set`PropertyName** methods as accessors* for the attached property; failing to do this will result in the property system being unable to use your attached property.

etc.

It is simply how to declare them which differs from normal DependencyProperties Syntax.